# How to determine RC filter cutoff of an ADC reading?

Tags: adc, low-pass, cutoff-frequency

I'm making a circuit where I'm voltage splitting a variable resistor and then sending the input to an ADC pin on an Arduino.

My question is, what frequency should I set a low pass filter for?  How do I got about figuring out what it should be?

For context, the variable resistor will be measuring changes in pressure from a foot.

Comment: Please draw a schematic with the tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually data acquisition with ADC uses a filter to avoid "aliasing" a phenomenon in which a spurious signal appears on the digital side while it does not exist in the real life analog signal, this is due to the ADC bandwidth limit. Another reason for the filter is to avoid noise.

In your specific application, the foot movement probably won't need a great bandwidth as we humans don't make extra fast movements. In theory you should put the filter frequency somewhere in the middle between the ADC bandwidth (half the sampling rate) and the signal bandwidth of interest.

In your case a 1 kHz or so can be good. Beware of how the RC filter will load the output of your pressure sensor.

Comment: your welcome, you can mark solved and vote up ;)

Comment: I consider 1 kHz to be a little too much. For mechanical (e.g. spring-mass systems) and "human movement" (e.g. arm movements) applications, I have personally used 20 Hz anti-alias filters with good results.

Comment: Also, other human-derived applications from electrocardiography and electromiography usually don't use anti-alias over 150 Hz.

Comment: ...I admit not having experience with applications with humans. A good thing from what @Vicente_Cunha says is that a filter cutting  below 50 Hz or 60 Hz has the advantage of blocking power line produced noise.